# bootstrap navbar background-color is not working but background works?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**In the first example I have used `background-color` to change the background color of the `navbar`to `orangered` but it is not working, In the next example I have used only `background` to change the color and now it is working, what is the reason for this behavior?**

**First Example**

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");

.navbar{
  background-color: orangered;  
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  "background-color: orangered;" is not working.
</div>
```

**Next Exmaple**

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");

.navbar{
  background: orangered;  
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  "background: orangered;" is working.
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `background-color` the original class **.navbar-inverse** `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%)` in the css takes over and is on top.

[image]

adding  `background-image: none;` in navbar css cancels it

**css**

```
.navbar {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-image: none;
}
```

when you use `background` it cancels the `background-image` css thus you see the color

[image]